# Transforming XML to JSON in WSO Api manager 3.2 using Script Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, esb, wso2-esb

**Description :** I am trying to transform from xml to json using script mediator in wso2 3.2 api manager. The issue which I am facing is the script mediator method getPayloadXML() is not able to pull out a specific value from xml where it always returns as ReferenceError: "code" is not defined. I tried multiple things but couldn't figure out how to achieve this. Any help from someone would be really appreciable.

**Response Mediation**

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="transform">    
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
   var envelope = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::fault-code.toString()
    
   var request ={"data":{"success":"true","message":"SuccessFull","faultcode":envelope}};

    mc.setPayloadJSON(request);
]]></script>
   <log level="full">
        <property name="Message" value="UpdatedMessage"/>
    </log>
    <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" />
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

**Original Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>210419-BA7CF-32444</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>Test123456</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsa:From>
            <wsa:Address>some data</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:From>
        <wsa:Action>some data</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <cbo:response xmlns:abr="url" xmlns:asic="url" client-reference1="A1" response-type="error" version="1.2">
            <cbo:error>
                <cbo:fault-code>CBOX017</cbo:fault-code>
                <cbo:fault-string>User account is inactive.</cbo:fault-string>
                <cbo:fault-actor/>
                <cbo:detail/>
            </cbo:error>
        </cbo:response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Expected Response (Transform To JSON)**

```
{
    "data": {
        "success": "true",
        "message": "SuccessFull",
        "faultcode":CBOX017
    }
}
```

**Error Logs**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-04-19 16:14:41,259] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} - {api:admin--equifaxACNCheck:v1.0.0} The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "code" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#2) in <Unknown Source> at line number 2
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "code" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1728)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.exec(<Unknown Source>)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
    ... 25 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-04-19 16:14:41,267] ERROR {API_LOGGER.admin--equifaxACNCheck} - The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "code" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#2) in <Unknown Source> at line number 2
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "code" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1728)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__2233.exec(<Unknown Source>)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Did you follow the guide in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/transforming-api-message-payload/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `ScriptMediator` has problem with parsing the `fault-code`. I think it is because the hyphen `-` already have meaning in JavaScript and in E4X. Maybe you can use alternate mediation with `PayloadFactory` like below:

```
    <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="transform">    
       <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"data":{"success":"$1", "message":"$2", "faultcode":"$3"}}</format>
            <args>
                <arg literal="false" value="true"/>
                <arg literal="false" value="SuccessFull"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*:fault-code"
                    literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <log level="full">
           <property name="Message" value="UpdatedMessage"/>
        </log>
        <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" />
    </sequence>
```

The `<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>` shouldn't be needed, because the payload factory should set that.

Comment: Out cannot be built - Continue in fail-safe mode org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid XPath expression for attribute expression : //*:fault-code

Comment: is there a way to transform payload with if condition using payload mediation?

Comment: Ok, the better XPath for that should be like: `//cbo:fault-code` but i don't see in you original response the namespace `xmlns:cbo= " ... "`
For `if condition` is better to use `FilterMediator`, or use `ScriptMediator`, it depends on complexity if condition

Comment: ok understood thanks for your suggestion. I have achieved this using //cbo:fault-code and regarding if condition I have set the property and fetched/checked that property in script mediator in if condition.